What's an efficient way to perform batch items delete in AppSync DynamoDB?
Amplify AppSync provides a way to execute a delete operation for a single item stored in DynamoDB. But what is the best way to delete all items that matches a value in a certain field?
Based on my initial searches, here's what I found:

Create a resolver, perform a BatchWrite Operation in DynamoDB but this can only delete up to 25 items max.

My GraphQL entities are ChatRoom and Messages. Messages for a ChatRoom could be more than thousands thus making the solution above seems inefficient.

BatchWriteItems can only take 25 items at a time, unfortunately a limit on the API.
AppSync aside, you have some SDK libraries that can chunk 1000s of items into batches of 25 for you. But that's not possible using AppSync.
